# input an array output bigger array related to input

Tags: arrays, pseudocode

suppose I have a arrays from each i want to produce b these are just examples

```
a=[4]=> b=[0,4]
a=[3,1]=>b=[0,3,3,4]
a=[2,2]=>b=[0,2,2,4]
a=[2,1,1]=>b=[0,2,2,3,3,4]
a=[3,4,2,5]=>b=[0,3,3,7,7,9,9,14]
```

I mean when getting 4 it should produce from 0 and then add it to it's content for example 4
or in a[2,1,1] first it will produce 0 and then it see that the next one in a is 1 so after again producing it it will compute 2+1 and assign it.so the output always will be twice size of the input.
i want a pseudo code for it my problem is that when it will repeat I can not write it.

Comment: try to explain what it does in more detail (I did not understand it). The pseudocode will maybe come naturally then.

Comment: in b[0,3,3,4] 3-0=3 and 4-3=1 these answers are respectively in a

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used JavaScript like syntax.

```
var a = new Array(3,4,2,5);
var b = new Array();
var bArrayIndex = 0;
b[bArrayIndex] = 0;
bArrayIndex++;
for(i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    b[bArrayIndex] = b[bArrayIndex-1] + a[i];
    if(i < a.length - 1) {
        b[bArrayIndex+1] = b[bArrayIndex];
    }
    bArrayIndex+=2;
}
for(i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
    document.write(b[i] + " ");
}
```